# Is the Google GMail client able to download attachments for arbitrary file types?

Tags: gmail, attachments

I emailed myself an epub the other day and went to the GMail app (v 2.3.5) on my android phone to download it.

While it showed me the attachment, I could not figure out how to download it. The email shows a pretty paperclip icon next to it, and at the bottom of email I get another pretty icon with a paperclip. But I cannot click(/press) on it. There is no preview/download button. The menu has no option to download it.

So my question is, is it actually possible?

I've seen a fair bit on forums suggesting it is not, but those are fairly dated threads. It seems somewhat inconceivable to me that one would not be able to download an attachment - as one person has put it, this seems like a feature shortcoming that is bordering on a bug.

An example of what I see is:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/attachwhat.png/

My phone: Samsung Galaxy S 2 running VillainRom 2.4.2, Gmail 2.3.5, email sent from Thunderbird 3.1.14 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know this was a new addition to the app recently, so it's surprising that it doesn't work for you.  I just tried emailing myself a `.epub` file and it worked just fine, I had a Download button to the right of the paperclip icon and attachment name.

I know that the Browser on many devices won't let you download any files that don't have a handler registered for their extension; perhaps this is related.  You can solve that issue via an app that registers for all files, such as [Download Crutch](http://www.androidtapp.com/download-crutch/); perhaps it will solve your attachment issues as well.  I'd reboot after installing it.  I have Download Crutch installed and have had no problems with it.

Comment: Fascinatingly enough, I forwarded the email to my friend on a Nexus Prime with GMail app ver 2.3.4.x (I forget the x) and he is able to download/preview the attachment. The other  odd thing is that he doesn't read ebooks it seems like he would be less likely to have so he is less likely to have an epub extension handler

Answer (score -1):

didnt find Download Crutch but another appp Download all files did the job pretty well.

Have fun 
Navneet

Comment: This answer is useless unless you share with us what other app you used.

Comment: He did give you the name of the application. It is 'DownloadAllFiles'.